# JAVA - Throw exception on default case

Tags: java, exception, throw

When I click `W`, `A`, `S` or `D` my element should walk in some direction.

I handle that with a switch case statement.

But, what if the user clicks on other key? I will not be able to get my new position.

Can I throw some exception on default case and do `try {...} catch {...}` after?

Below is my code:

```
private boolean checkPos(String c) {
    int newPosX, newPosY;

    switch(c.toUpperCase().charAt(0)){
    case 'W':
        newPosX = oldPosX + 1;
        break;
    case 'A':
        newPosY = oldPosY() - 1;
        break;
    case 'S':
        newPosX = oldPosX() - 1;
        break;
    case 'D':
        newPosY = oldPosY() + 1;
        break;
    default:
        //throw exception???
        return false;
    }

    System.out.println("input:" + c.toUpperCase().charAt(0));
    System.out.println("OLD POSITION: (" + oldPosY() + ";" + oldPosX() + ")");
    System.out.println("NEW POSITION: (" + newPosY + ";" + newPosX + ")");
}
```

Can someone give me an hand?

Comment: You have used a games for this kind of navigation before, what did those programs do? Did they throw an exception?

Comment: you could just do nothing. Would mean that pressing any other key apart from W, A, S or D would not adjust the position at all.

Comment: What about doing nothing?!

Answer (score 2):

throwing an exception seems like a very bad way to do this since they are expensive and should only be used when they are needed instead you should set your default case to tell the user their input is invalid and loop back round to ask for a new input.

```
default: System.out.println("Invalid data");
requestPos(); // which i presume will bring you back to checkpos with more data
break;
```

the print out of invalid part is probably not needed but depending on your game it might be nice to inform the user